# What happens if I manually change the USER environment variable

Tags: bash, users, environment-variables

After running `env` in the terminal to check if some of my other variables were persistant across settings I noticed the `USER=xxx` environment variable.

I've had to reinstall Ubuntu before after fooling around with some system files so this time I'm nervous to simply experiment with things myself.

What would happen if I ran `sudo export USER=NewUser`?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing dangerous! It will only change the value for `$USER` variable until you close current shell session. But, until to close the current shell session, the new value will be used and because of this it is possible that some applications or scripts where this variable is used to not run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: nothing

The environment variables are only valid during the actual session (e.g. as long as you don't close the Terminal). But because you open a new session for root with sudo which exit emidiately after changing the environment this command will not even touch your session.

If you want to permanentaly change environment variables you can use either `/etc/profiles` or `~\.bashrc`